# Using clang-cl.exe to do cross compilation?

Tags: clang, cross-compiling

I want to do cross compilation with clang-cl.exe, but didn't got much info via searching. The clang parameter `-target <tripple>` also doesn't work. Is it supported to do cross compilation?

Comment: What are to trying to cross compile to?

Comment: `clang-cl.exe` is a clang interface/driver that has command-line switches compatible with Microsoft's C / C++ compiler (`cl.exe`). It's meant for dropping into build processes on Windows that expect the Microsoft compiler. It's not a cross-compiler.

Comment: @Richard Pennington, I want to compile for x64, but it seems there is no separate 64-bit LLVM for Windows as VC++ compilers do.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, I am just want to use it to build x64 obj and link it by 64-bit VC++ linker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use clang-cl.exe to compile 64-bit binaries by using the `-m64` flag.

Source: [LLVM mailing list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2014-July/075121.html)